# Use strings in a list as variable names in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of string elements like `user_contract = ['ZNZ6','TNZ6','ZBZ6']`

I have a data set which has nested list structure like `data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

I want to assign each of the `user_contract` strings as variable names for each of the `data` nested list, in the respective order.

I know I can do this manually by typing `ZNZ6, TNZ6, ZBZ6 = data`. I don't think this is flexible enough, and I would have to manually change this line every time I change the names in `user_contract`.

Is there a way where I can make use of the `user_contract` variable to assign data to each of its elements?

Comment: Use a dictionary for this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: wonderful, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code can help you:

```
user_contract = ['ZNZ6','TNZ6','ZBZ6']
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
dictionary = dict(zip(user_contract, data))
print(dictionary)
```

It creates a dictionary from the two lists and prints it:

```
python3 pyprog.py 
{'ZBZ6': [7, 8, 9], 'ZNZ6': [1, 2, 3], 'TNZ6': [4, 5, 6]}
```

Comment: This is a really neat trick, I was just wondering how the efficiency of this compared with a pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exec` to evaluate expressions and assign to variables dynamically:

```
>>> names = ','.join(user_contract)
>>> exec('{:s} = {:s}'.format(names, str(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to assign the values:

```
myvars = {user_contract[i]: data[i] for i in range(len(user_contract))}
```

Then you can access the values like so

```
myvars['TNZ6']
> [1, 2, 3]
```